# PowerAutomate JSON - Convert Array of Object to String

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

So, I have a JSON object that contains an array of users who are members of a group. I would like to take all of those users and squish them into one nice string and put that string into a sharepoint list.

I THINK I would use compose, but honestly I've never used it before and I have no idea how. Really, the hope is to convert this:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "e3eec502-97a5-47cc-ae81-82c34c4e9b4a",
      "businessPhones": [],
      "displayName": "User one",
      "givenName": "User1",
      "jobTitle": null,
      "mail": "email@email.com",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "surname": "one",
      "userPrincipalName": "user.one@email.com"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "ab02d0c4-5770-4a54-95ec-200fb55dfd27",
      "businessPhones": [],
      "displayName": "User two",
      "givenName": "User2",
      "jobTitle": null,
      "mail": "email@email.com",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "surname": "two",
      "userPrincipalName": "User.two@email.com"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "15610147-ca81-47c3-bd34-ad046ff9ac46",
      "businessPhones": [],
      "displayName": "User three",
      "givenName": "User3",
      "jobTitle": null,
      "mail": null,
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "surname": "three",
      "userPrincipalName": "user.three@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

To this

`User one, User two, User three`

Any ideas or resources I can check out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following ...

Loaded your JSON (minus the `@` symbols because PA doesn't like them) into a variable so I can loop over it.

[image: Data]

I then created two other variables, one to hold the concatenated string as it's being worked on and the other to hold the end result.

[image: Variables]

I then looped over the array of values and pulled out the `displayName` property and appended it (with a leading comma) to the `Concatenated String` variable.

[image: Loop]

Expression 1 = `variables('Data')['value']`

Expression 2 = `item()['displayName']`

The final step is to then remove the leading comma with an expression.

[image: Result]

Expression = `substring(variables('Concatenated String'), 1)`

**Result**

[image: Result]

**Flow**

[image: Flow]

Comment: Welp, had problems. The issue is I'm doing this inside an "apply each" because this is a graph API callthat is looping through multiple groups. So the skeleton is

Comment: It’s all the same thing, it’s just a matter of adapting my answer to your flow. If you have another specific error, detail it and I might be able to help.

Comment: Got it up and running! Checkmark for you! Appreciate!

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using the [Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action), [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/data-operations#use-the-select-action) and [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/data-operations#use-the-join-action) actions.

The finished flow will be trigger by a button and contain the following actions:

1. Initialize variable - Initialize a variable with the data we want to manipulate
2. Parse JSON - Assigns a schema to the data allowing us to more easily access the array
3. Select - Converts the object array into a string array
4. Join - Concatenates all the items within the string array

and look like this:

[image: Power Automate flow]

Each action needs to be implemented as follows:

### 1. Initialize variable

First add an initialize variable action with the following values:

- Name: **data**
- Value: The JSON you want to process (as noted in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653486/63295) the "@" characters should be removed)

[image: Initialize Variable Settings]

### 2. Parse JSON

You then need to add a Parse JSON action to tell power automate the schema of the data assigned in the initialize variable action. This will allow us to more easily reference the array in the next step. The values should be set to:

- Content: The **data** variable
- Schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "odata.context": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Parse JSON action]

### 3. Select

Now add a Select action. This action is normally used to transform one array of objects. However, we can use it to return an array of strings. To do this  click the **Switch Map to text mode** button.

[image: Select Action - Switch Map to text mode]

Although you can achieve the desired result by using the expression `item()['displayName']`, it's possible to construct more complex string by combining the values within the object. For example, we could combine the **displayName** and **mail** properties by setting the **map** value to `"@{item()['displayName']} - @{item()['mail']}"`.

[image: Select Action]

### 4. Join

Finally use a Join action to concatenate the string array produced by the Select action with a specific separator (in your case a comma and space character `,` ).

[image: Join action]